# MS Access Consolidating Ranges of Numbers

Tags: ms-access

I want to be able to collapse multiple contiguous ranges into as few ranges as possible.

I have already been able to do this in Excel by using a macro to paste formulas into adjacent cells.  I know I can accomplish this similarly using a recordset and iterating through the data calculating formulas as I go, but I hope that someone knows a simpler more efficient way to do this so that it is not impractical to do with larger data sets.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
Origin   Low    High    Dest
SDF     40200  40309    EWR
SDF     40310  40370    EWR
SDF     70000  70800    ORD
SDF     40371  40402    EWR
SDF     40508  40580    EWR
```

... and the desired output of the process would be:

```
Origin   Low    High    Dest
SDF     40200  40402    EWR
SDF     40508  40580    EWR
SDF     70000  70800    ORD
```

Comment: It is impossible. The maximal amount of adjacent regions which must me collapsed into one is unknown, so only iterational algorythm may be used - but MS Access does not support recursive queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to open an ordered recordset using VBA and iterate over each record, testing whether the differences between the High of one record and Low of the next differs by more than one.

In draft code, this might look like the following (where `SourceTable` is the source table, and `DestTable` is an existing table which may be used to store the output):

```vb
Function ConsolidateRanges()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

    Dim org As String
    Dim low As Long
    Dim hig As Long
    Dim des As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from SourceTable order by origin, dest, low, high")

    If Not rs1.EOF Then
        dbs.Execute "delete from DestTable"
        Set rs2 = dbs.OpenRecordset("DestTable")

        rs1.MoveFirst
        GetRange rs1, org, low, hig, des
        rs1.MoveNext
        Do Until rs1.EOF
            If org <> rs1!origin Or des <> rs1!dest Or rs1!low - hig > 1 Then
                AddRange rs2, org, low, hig, des
                GetRange rs1, org, low, hig, des
            Else
                hig = rs1!high
            End If
            rs1.MoveNext
        Loop
        AddRange rs2, org, low, hig, des
        rs2.Close
    End If
    rs1.Close
End Function

Function GetRange(rstIn As Recordset, strOrg As String, lngLow As Long, lngHig As Long, strDes As String)
    With rstIn
        strOrg = .Fields("Origin")
        lngLow = .Fields("Low")
        lngHig = .Fields("High")
        strDes = .Fields("Dest")
    End With
End Function

Function AddRange(rstOut As Recordset, strOrg As String, lngLow As Long, lngHig As Long, strDes As String)
    With rstOut
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Origin") = strOrg
        .Fields("Low") = lngLow
        .Fields("High") = lngHig
        .Fields("Dest") = strDes
        .Update
    End With
End Function
```